# Главные члены предложения (2)

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Помогите, пожалуйста, определить главные члены в предложении.
**Знать природу своего края, его историю, быт — это значит укоренять в себе любовь к Родине.**

Answer (score 2):

***Знать*** природу своего края, его историю, быт — это значит **укоренять** в себе любовь к Родине.

Тире ставится в предложениях, в которых сказуемое [укоренять] присоединяется к подлежащему [знать] с помощью слов **это, вот, это есть, значит** (в значении *это есть*), **это значит**.
[Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/706-17_tire_mezhdu_podlezhaschim_i_skazuemym.html)

```
Любить —   
     это значит: 
               в глубь двора  
вбежать
      и до ночи грачьей,
блестя топором,
           рубить дрова,
силой
      своей
            играючи.
```

В. В. Маяковский

*Знать — это значит располагать информацией, сведениями, данными. Осознавать — это значит отдавать себе отчет в том, что происходит* (из статьи).